# DropDownList does not update on changing selected index

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm currently working on an old asp website but im running into some problems. I have to say that im not very up to speed with asp.net. I have a DropDownList with items (days - Monday / Friday) that i have hard coded.

I'm trying to change the index based on the date that gets selected by a calender control that inserts the date in text form into a text-field. On the text-changed event of the text-field I'm trying to change the index.

When I put a quick watch on the selected index I see that index change correctly based on the date but for some reason the actual control is not updated on the website.

I already enabled autoPostBack but that did not help unfortunately.

**textChanged code:**

```
            tbLoadFrom.Text = Util.ToTime(_programSession.GetTime(customer, address, customer.DefaultLoadTimeFrom, "LoadFrom", Util.ToIntBasedDayOfWeek(Convert.ToDateTime(tbLoadDate.Text).DayOfWeek)));
            tbLoadTill.Text = Util.ToTime(_programSession.GetTime(customer, address, customer.DefaultLoadTimeTill, "LoadTill", Util.ToIntBasedDayOfWeek(Convert.ToDateTime(tbLoadDate.Text).DayOfWeek)));
            ddl_LoadTimeDay.SelectedIndex = Util.ToIntBasedDayOfWeek(Convert.ToDateTime(tbLoadDate.Text).DayOfWeek);
            ddl_LoadTimeDay.DataBind();
```

**DropDownList:**

```
                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_LoadTimeDay" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_LoadTimeDay_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Maandag</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Dinsdag</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Woensdag</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Donderdag</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Vrijdag</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Default</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: show some code this way no one can't help you

Comment: no code..no fun to help..

Comment: @KrunalPatil Sorry added some code ;)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Added some code :)

Comment: you dont need to call DataBind after setting SelectedIndex

Comment: Can you please Past formLoad and ddl_LoadTimeDay_SelectedIndexChanged events code?

Comment: @EmadMokhtar I found the problem. After checking the aspx source I saw that our previous programmer had put a separate update-panel around the date text-field. I removed that and called the other update panel that contains the Dropdownbox / text-fields to update on text change. This works like a charm. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date text-field was in a separate update-panel. I removed this panel and called the parent update-panel to update. This works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In text changed event remove DataBind() ofr the Dropdownlist

```
  tbLoadFrom.Text = Util.ToTime(_programSession.GetTime(customer, address, customer.DefaultLoadTimeFrom, "LoadFrom", Util.ToIntBasedDayOfWeek(Convert.ToDateTime(tbLoadDate.Text).DayOfWeek)));
  tbLoadTill.Text = Util.ToTime(_programSession.GetTime(customer, address, customer.DefaultLoadTimeTill, "LoadTill", Util.ToIntBasedDayOfWeek(Convert.ToDateTime(tbLoadDate.Text).DayOfWeek)));
   ddl_LoadTimeDay.SelectedIndex = Util.ToIntBasedDayOfWeek(Convert.ToDateTime(tbLoadDate.Text).DayOfWeek);
  ddl_LoadTimeDay.DataBind(); //Remove this
```

This line will make ASP.NET to load the data again from the datasource and your selected Index will be clear and set to default.

Comment: I removed DataBind() but its still not updated. I also noticed that the textboxes are not updating.

Comment: I also noticed that the Date textbox is in a separate UpdatePanel. Could that maybe causing the other updatepanel not to see the change?